# Extending function defined on a Borel set to all of the real line

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $B$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb R$ and $f:B \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a bounded ($|f(x)| < M$ for all $x \in B$) increasing (not strictly increasing) function. Prove that there exists an increasing function $g:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $f = g$ on $B$.

My attempt:

Define $g$ in the following way:

If $x \in B$ then $g(x) = f(x)$.

If $x \notin B$ and there does not exist $y \in B$ such that $y>x$ then define $g(x) = M$.

If $x \notin B$ and there does not exist $y \in B$ such that $y<x$ then define $g(x) = -M$.

Otherwise define $g(x)$ as the supremum of $\{ f(y):y \in B, y<x \}$.

Is my $g$ correct? I haven't used the fact that $B$ is a Borel set.

Comment: I would define it as $\sup$ over $y \le x$, $y \in B$ just so it agrees with $f$ at a given point in $B$.

Comment: Looks sound, and yeah, doesn't seem to need Borel.  Just give it the next higher value for missing values

Comment: Aren't $f$ and $g$ requierd to be Borel measurable?